# Ubuntu One API Java - how to use REST and AccessToken?

Tags: java, ubuntu-one-api

I am writing a java app in eclipse that backups data to several consumer-cloud-services encrypted and redundant.

So far, I successfully implemented the authentication process, as it is described in the [documentation](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/files/store_files/android).

At this point, I do not know how to proceed. The next step would be implementing the auth with the stored AccessToken and afterwars implementing upload/download/listing functionality through the REST API.

1. I think I have to store the String oauth.getSerialized(). How do I authenticate with this String afterwards? This does not work e.g.:

   ```
   AuthenticateResponse oauth = api.authenticate(serialized);
   api.setAuthorizer(new OAuthAuthorizer(oauth));
   ```
2. Can someone tell me please, how I can use the REST API with java? There is no explanation or link in the developers area as far as I saw.

And btw, I wasted at least one hour trying to fix errors, because some needed libraries are listet *after* the example code. :/

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this.

As you mention you are able to store the auth tokens. So following is the way forward:

Objective: Create the U1FileAPI object

```
public U1FileAPI(String appPackageName, String appVersion,
    HttpClient httpClient, Authorizer authorizer)
```

Constructor accepts :

1. appPackageName >This is same as package name you have given @ the
   time of authentication creation
2. appVersion >This is same as appVersion name you have given @ the time of authentication creation
3. httpClient > create a new one HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
4. authorizer > For this you require little effort:

   ```
   ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(
       new FileInputStream("/file/where/you/save/auth/tokens"));
   ```

Create the OAuthAuthorizer object:

```
OAuthAuthorizer aOuth = OAuthAuthorizer.getWithTokens(
    input.readObject().toString(), new HmacSha1MessageSigner());
```

Now you are good to go for U1FileAPI creation:

```
U1FileAPI   uOneFs = new U1FileAPI(package_api, version, httpClient, aOuth);
```

Use the expose methods of uOneFs to solve your actual backup requirements.

While browsing found Cross reference for Ubuntu One, hope it will also help you to understand this better:
http://code.metager.de/source/xref/ubuntu/one/files-java-library/src/main/com/ubuntuone/api/files/U1FileAPI.java#resourceClient